# NPOI Mapper throws "Wrong Local header signature: 0x41D" exception

Tags: .net, npoi

I get this result with simple NPOI Mapper initialization:

```cs
Mapper map = new Mapper("pathtofile\\xxx.xlsx");
```

=>
`ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: 'Wrong Local header signature: 0x41D'`

The file is opened by Excel normally, without password. Moreover, the author of xslx in the metadata is `Apache NPOI`.

Did somebody have similar error?